# Deleting CommandButtons by name in VBA Word 2010

Tags: vba, ms-word

In a word template, I have two command buttons namely

1. **[Add section]** which is named "CommandButton1"
2. **[Done]** - which is named "CommandButton2"

I need both buttons to be deleted at the click of [Done]

Here's my code so far

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = ThisDocument.InlineShapes.Count To 1 Step -1

      With ThisDocument.InlineShapes(i)
          If .OLEFormat.Object.Name = "CommandButton1" Then
              .Delete
          End If
       End With
   Next

End Sub
```

The code is a combination of snippets I found online. I had only added "CommandButton1" for testing purpose and was planning to add a check for CommandButton2 as well if this works.

On executing the code it successfully deletes CommandButton2 and gives me an error "*Objected cannot be accessed on a horizontal line*" without deleting CommandButton1.

I tried messing around with the "count to 1 Step -1" part (I don't know what they imply), but it all results in the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for ... next` loop is done from the end (ThisDocument.InlineShapes.Count) to the start of the array to be sure to go through all items that need to be deleted.

For instance, going from first to last item, if your array has 3 items:

- Object(1)
- Object(2)
- Object(3)

By deleting the first item, the array would be re-ordered, and Object(2) will get index 1 and Object(3) will get index 2. Using `for ... next`  could lead you to an issue as total number of items in your array is not the same than when you started your loop.

I'd rather use a `do while ... loop` in this case:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    On Error Resume Next
    Err.Clear

    Dim i As Integer
    i = ThisDocument.InlineShapes.Count
    Do While (i > 0)
        If ThisDocument.InlineShapes(i).OLEFormat.ClassType = "Forms.CommandButton.1" Then

            If ThisDocument.InlineShapes(i).OLEFormat.Object.Name = "CommandButton1" _
            Or ThisDocument.InlineShapes(i).OLEFormat.Object.Name = "CommandButton2" Then

                If Err.Number = 0 Then
                    ThisDocument.InlineShapes(i).Delete
                End If
                Err.Clear

            End If

        End If
        i = i - 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh we meet again :). You've been of great help today. The solution works beautifully, both buttons were deleted. There's just one weird thing, I still get the "This member cannot be accessed on a horizontal line" error. Anyway of suppressing the message, or something.

Comment: Yes :-) weird error message, does Word give you the line where it occurs? If it is in the `CommandButton2_Click()` sub, you could try to add an `On Error Resume Next` as first instruction. Well anyway, it would be better to find and solve the issue.

Comment: Your right about the error, I tried `On Error Resume Next` , it does suppress the error message, but now goes ahead and deletes a couple of horizontal lines I had added to the template as well.

Comment: So strange. The error message's gone but it still deletes the horizontal lines. Basically acting like the `if` statement is fulfilled in all cases.

Comment: Another update, to check any error before doing the delete. Not my favorite... It would be better to test for the InlineShape item type or something like that and exclude what is not CommandButton.

Comment: Finally!! Works like a charm :-). I'll try playing around with the code to run a "type" test or something as you suggested. For now this works beautifully. Can't thank you enough for today.. :) learnt a lot. Thanks again